# Installing R packages super slow on AWS ec2 through terminal compared to on my mac laptop

Tags: r, linux, macos, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Installing R packages has been super slow on my AWS ec2 computer. I connect to it through terminal. The ec2 OS is amazon linux 2 (red hat-based), though I have also had the same issue trying an ubuntu os on ec2. Compared to on my mac laptop (which can install the same packages in a few seconds), installing packages on my ec2 computer (while running R using the "R" command, tried both "R" and "sudo R") takes several minutes. I have tried running different types of ec2 configurations in terms of RAM and processing power (up to r4.16xlarge 64 cpus 488 memory) with no improvement to the level of speed my laptop has. Additional details: my laptop is the most recent MacBook Pro 16 GB 2133 MHz LPDDR3 3.1 GHz Intel Core i7 Intel HD Graphics 630 1536 MB and I install packages usually in Rstudio using install.packages().

Comment: Packages on Linux have to be compiled, whereas I think on Mac you get binary packages. So there will definitely be some difference. If you can live with slightly old packages you can install the versions from the Linux distribution's repositories, although that will only cover a small number of packages.

Comment: Thanks @Marius ! I recall that when I used to use a university computing cluster and install packages to my account there it was much quicker. Any idea why this is? From your previous answer all I can think of is that maybe most packages were already pre-loaded to the system (compiled) before I even installed them to my specific account.